# How does the compiler deal with lambda expression in java?

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-construction, functional-programming, jvm

Lets assume that we have the following code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("separated thread");
    }
});
t.start();
```

The replaceable of the above in Java 8 is:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("separated thread"));
t.start();
```

Now as far as I know lambda expression in other languages that runs on the **JVM** for example **Scala** and **Groovy**, is simply treated as an anonymous block
of code where the compiler replaces the expression with its equivalent anonymous inner class resulting a new class for each call, i know for a fact that the above is not good at all in term of size and runtime.

Is this the case in Java? if not how does it deal with lambda (**in details**)?
I would also appreciate; if the mechanism behind using invokedDynamic feature to supports lambda is explained?

Comment: AFAIK lambdas are just another way of writing anonymous classes, i.e. the compiler should transform them. Thus both variants should basically equal from a runtime point of view.

Comment: @Thomas Apparently (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827262/how-will-java-lambda-functions-be-compiled?noredirect=1&lq=1) the compiler does not do this transformation, but leaves it up to the runtime how exactly it wants to generate code for the lambda on the fly.

Comment: And I believe the latest Scala version (it requires Java8) also makes use of this more-performant mechanism.

Comment: @Thilo I couldn't find any satisfying answer in both of the possible duplicates, I'm curious about the mechanism behind using invokedDynamic feature to supports lambda and deals with it differently

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26257532/14955

Comment: @Thilo yup that's the one, Thank you very much :)