# What are the tradeoffs for different approaches when creating a comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

Suppose I have a `Record` class with a `String name` (could be any other type) attribute. In another class I have a method `order(List<Record>)` which needs to sort the list by `name`. To do this, I want to create a custom stateless `Comparator`. I have seen three options that are commonly used:

1. Static comparator

   ```
   private static final Comparator<Record> STATIC_COMPARATOR = new StaticComparator();
   private static class StaticComparator implements Comparator<Record> {
       @Override
       public int compare(Record m1, Record m2) {
           return m1.getName().compareTo(m2.getName());
       }
   }

   void order(List<Record> records) {
       records.sort(STATIC_COMPARATOR);
   }
   ```
2. Singleton comparator

   ```
   private static enum SingletonComparator implements Comparator<Record> {
       INSTANCE;

       @Override
       public int compare(Record m1, Record m2) {
           return m1.getName().compareTo(m2.getName());
       }
   }

   void order(List<Record> records) {
       records.sort(SingletonComparator.INSTANCE);
   }
   ```
3. Use `Comparator.comparing()`

   ```
   void order(List<Record> records) {
       records.sort(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName));
   }
   ```

Assuming `order()` gets called a lot, what are the tradeoffs for each approach? How do they compare on matters such as serialization, thread safety, and performance?

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same. 3 is the same (except creates a new `Comparator` instance) if the JVM you use implements method references by returning the same instance.

Comment: The main difference between 1 and 2 is the thread safety in creation of the instance. For the comparators you post, however, this is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't think so. `static` initializer runs behind a lock. The code generated for the `enum` is equivalent.

Comment: @sotiros yeah, you are right.

Comment: Your comparator is stateless, so serialization and thread safety are non-issues. As for performance, you're probably talking nanosecond difference. Even with millions of comparisons.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Couldn't performance be a problem in the third case, when using `Comparator.comparing()`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Do you know if the HotSpot or the OpenJDK implement method references by returning the same instance? Is there a name for this feature?

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you make your Record class implement a `Comparable<Record>` interface and then override the `compareTo()` method instead. That way, you can sort your List with ease. Would this be an option for you, or do you really want to stick to using `Comparator`s?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524445/does-a-lambda-expression-create-an-object-on-the-heap-every-time-its-executed/27524543#27524543

Comment: @theguywhodreams Thanks. But the `Record` class is just an example. Implementing `Comparable` is not a good option in my real problem.