# What is going on underneath with this lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Take this simple piece of code

```
new Thread(() -> {

}).start();
```

I know it works, but how do I write my own class to allow someone to use it in the same manner?

Comment: What do you mean by "to allow someone to use it in the same manner"?

Comment: This is lamba expression, java 8 addition to make code as unreadable as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda works on  [Functional Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8), so if your class or method have ability to take such interface as parameter then you can use your class/method that manner.

```
new Thread(() -> {

}).start();
```

This code works as `Thread` has a overloaded constructor which take functional interface `Runnable` as arguments.

**Example: How to write own class**

Here `DoWork` is our functional Interface which has only abstract method `doit`

```
public interface DoWork {
    public  void doit(String str);
}
```

Let we have a class named `MyClass` whose constructor take `DoWork` as arguments and have a method `startWork` to start the work(Ordinary Method).

```
public class MyClass {
    DoWork dw;
    public MyClass(DoWork dw) {
        this.dw = dw;
    }
    public void startWork(String s){
        dw.doit(s);
    }

}
```

That's all, we can test it in `Main`

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyClass(str -> System.out.println(str)).startWork("Hello print it!!!");
    }

}
```

We can also use lambda with method parameter which take functional interface.

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test(str ->System.out.println(str), "Hello world!!!");

    }

    public static void test(DoWork d, String str) {
        d.doit(str);
    }

}
```

For more about Lambda you can see http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the full code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         //do things
    }
}).start();
```

Lambda expressions let you express instances of single-method classes more compactly.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas noticed that deep down there is a difference:

> The anonymous class declaration still creates a separate anonymous class, while the lambda adds a hidden method and uses invokedynamic, basically using method reference, so there is a difference behind the scene. Functionally they are equivalent, though.

Comment: sorry I mean in java 8 not older versions

Comment: Lambda expressions let you express instances of single-method classes more compactly. There is nothing else going on.

Comment: What this means is that, if you want to be able to use a lambda in your own functions, they just need to have a parameter whose type is a class or interface with exactly one abstract method, known as a [Functional Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)

Comment: 1) You have a close-parenthesis too many on `new Runnable()`. 2) The anonymous class declaration still creates a separate anonymous class, while the lambda adds a hidden method and uses `invokedynamic`, basically using method reference, so there *is* a difference behind the scene. Functionally they are equivalent, though.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the parenthesis. I didn't know about the `invokedynamic`.

Comment: @nbokmans Yeah, I thought the same as you, until I noticed that lambdas didn't create a `$1` class file. Disassembler told the rest of the story.

Comment: with your guys help I figured how to do it but it only seems to work with an interface not a class. Is there a function pointer in Java?

Comment: @John E.: maybe you should check [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) first.

Comment: @Andreas: not only the compiled code differs, there are [even more differences at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27524445/2711488)…