# How lambda expression works with Predicate?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I need more clarification about lambda expression. How `'p'` represents `List<Person> people`? Could you explain clear to me

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Person("Mohamed", 69));
people.add(new Person("Doaa", 25));
people.add(new Person("Malik", 6));
Predicate<Person> pred = (p) -> p.getAge() > 65;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `p` is not a `List<Person>` but a `Person`.

```
Predicate<Person> pred = p -> p.getAge() > 65;
```

This lambda expression declares 1 formal parameter and returns a `boolean`. As such, it can be represented as a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) (because the `Predicate` interface has a single functional method with this exact signature, called [`test`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-)). The type of `p` will be determined by the type of the `Predicate` you are creating.

For example, in the following code, `p` will be a `List<Person>`:

```
Predicate<List<Person>> predicate = p -> p.isEmpty();
```

Comment: can you explain about (p) in the code and how iteration happen here?

Comment: @KannanThangadurai `(p)`, the same as `p`, (the parenthesis are not needed in this case) is the formal parameter of the lambda expression. I suggest you read [this Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) on lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas in java it is just a syntax shugar for [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Code from you example is equal to

```
List<person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Person("Mohamed", 69));
people.add(new Person("Doaa", 25));
people.add(new Person("Malik", 6));

Predicate<person> pred = new Predicate<person>() {
    public boolean test(person p) {
        return p.getAge() > 65;
    }
}
```

To simplify syntax in java you can skip type declaration in lambda expression and add only name of value, like you did.

```
Predicate<person> pred = (p) -> p.getAge() > 65;
```

Or if you want, you can write something like this

```
Predicate<person> pred = (person p) -> p.getAge() > 65;
```

Its to be noted you can skip type declaration only if it can be counted from lambda code somehow. For example

```
Comparator<String> comp
= (firstStr, secondStr) // Same as (String firstStr, String secondStr)
    -> Integer.compare(firstStr.length(),secondStr.length());
```

Comment: Lambdas are *not* syntactic sugar for anonymous classes. Lambda expressions and anonymous classes share some common use cases but that’s all. For these common use cases you can write an anonymous class that is equivalent to the lambda expression basically doing the same thing. But they are not the same thing.

Comment: And what is the differencein java?
In bytecode we will get anonimous class anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @user2982622, absolutely not. And even aside from bytecode they are different (lambdas are stateless, have different lexical scope and so on).

Comment: As pointed out by Tagir, there are semantic differences and a different lexical scope on source code level, i.e. lambdas can’t define instance variables nor invoke methods of the functional interface they’re going to implement and `this` and `super` have a different meaning. Further, there are [some practical differences at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524445/does-a-lambda-expression-create-an-object-on-the-heap-every-time-its-executed/27524543#27524543) and [big differences on the byte code level](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html)