# Why does Map.compute() take a BiFunction

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java-8

I don't understand why `Map.compute()` and `Map.computeIfPresent()` take `BiFunction` parameters as well as `Map.computeIfAbsent()` a `Function`:

`V compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction)`
`V computeIfPresent(K key, BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction)`
`V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction)`

I'd expect an ordinary [`Function<? super V, ? extends V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), mapping the old value to a new value, resp. a [`Supplier<? extends V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) for the new value. The caller already has the key (first argument) so the function or the supplier can already make use of it. All examples I found don't use the key. The reasons that come to my mind:

- the key must be (effectively) `final` -- that's easy to manage
- there are some fancy easy-to-use method references

But I don't believe these are viable reasons for this design. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: There's one less variable to capture in the lambda.

Comment: 1) "The caller already has the key (first argument) so the function or the supplier can already make use of it." I don't see how you would take the key into account without having it as a parameter in the function. 2) "All examples I found don't use the key." Well, easier to ignore an unused parameter than to use a parameter that is not present.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is that expensive?

Comment: @tobias_k (1) just use it, (2) adding parameters without a purpose is a bad thing. so my question is: why is it not superfluous.

Comment: “The caller already has the key” … unless the BiFunction is a method reference, in which case the method won't know the key's value, unless that key is passed in as an argument.

Comment: @VGR yes. i wrote that.

Comment: @steffen: it can make the difference between capturing and noncapturing, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488

Comment: @VGR, sometimes having key parameter is just unnecessary burden. Without it we could write `map.computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new).add(value)`, now we need to write `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value)` introducing useless `k`.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: it’s indeed more often the case that I don’t need the key than that I need it. However, in my projects, certain function transformation utility methods are part of the standard toolset as they come in handy at various places, i.e. I can use `map.computeIfAbsent(key, dropArg(ArrayList::new)). …`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may see [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) as the single-entry pendant of [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) whereas the latter *requires* the key as a parameter, but it’s natural to support the same function as input to both operations and the API is *consistent* here: it always provides the key as parameter to the function.

Generally, providing the key raises the reusability of existing functions, be it method references or ordinary `class` implementations (i.e. non-lambda) of the `BiFunction` interface. But this reusability may also affect the performance of lambda expressions given the existing JRE implementation:

[As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488), lambda expressions capturing values from the surrounding context may end up in individual instances for each capturing process, whereas lambda expressions only using their parameters (non-capturing lambdas) will end up as a singleton instance. In contrast, having an otherwise unused parameter has no performance impact. So receiving the key as a parameter is preferable for that reason as well.