# Where variables of out scope is stored for lambda expressions

Tags: java, memory, lambda, java-8

As I know for inner and anonimous classes variables of outer scope is stored in generated bytecode (e.g. OuterClass$1.class). 
I would like to know where is stored variables of the next example:

```
public Function<Integer, Integer> curring(Integer elem) {
    return x -> x * elem;
}

Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).stream().map(curring(2)).map(curring(5)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Lambda is translated to methods, not classes. Does it mean that for this 2 calls would be generated 2 separate methods ?

Comment: Have found an interesting reading on this topic: [Translation of lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html)

Comment: that not an *interesting* reading, that's *THE* reading about lambda translation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This expression `x -> x * elem;` is going to be de-sugared to a **static** method, that looks like this:

```
  private static Integer lambda$curring$0(int x, int y){
      return x*y;
  }
```

Because you are `capturing` the `elem` variable inside the lambda, the lambda is said to be a `stateful lambda`.

On the other hand, your `map` operation needs an actual instance of `java.util.Function` - and that is generated **at runtime** that will kind of look like this:

```
 final class Test2$$Lambda$1 implements java.util.function.Function {
      private final Integer arg$1;

      private Test2$$Lambda$1(Integer arg$1){
          this.arg$1 = arg$1;
      }

      // static factory method
      private static java.util.function.Function get$Lambda(Integer i){
            return new Test2$$Lambda$1(i); // instance of self
      }

       public Integer apply(Integer x) {
          return YourClass.lambda$curring$0(this.arg$1, x);    
       }
 }
```

Before `Function.apply` (inside your map operation) is called a **new instance** of `Test2$$Lambda$1` is generated via the static factory method `get$Lambda`.  This is needed "carry" the `elem` variable.

Because of that **every time map gets called a new instance is created**.

Since your Stream has five initial elements, there will be 10 instances created - for the two `map` operations.

But *generally* this is an implementation detail that might easily change one day - so don't rely on it. Also the creation and collection (by garbage collector) of this short lived instances are quite cheap  and it will not impact your app almost at all.

Comment: A bit of nitpicking: when you implement the raw `Function`, you’ll need an `Object apply(Object x)` method and type casts. This is what actually happens currently in the generated code. Further, `this.i` has to be `this.arg$1`. It is correct that the captured value will be the first parameter and the function parameter (`x`) the second. In the generated `lambda$curring$0` method, it would be less confusing to use `elem` and `x` as name for these parameters, rather than `x` and `y`…

Comment: @Holger that is by far not nitpicking in my world. It is quite amazing that this answer is actually hours of reading *your* (that's the main keyword in this comment) other answers and much debugging and lots of bytecode... thx for the advices.

Answer (score 3):

Everytime you call your `curring(..)` method, it will create a new object. So yes, you will have 2 objects.

This is because your lambda is not stateless, aka it is not working only on its own. It needs to capture an external variable, `elem`.

If a fixed number like `2` was used in your lambda rather than `elem`:

```
public Function<Integer, Integer> curring() {
    return x -> x * 2;
}
```

Your lambda would be stateless. It would not capture any external variable. In that case, your lambda would be a singleton called multiple times.

Notice that this behavior is JVM-dependant, and the above is from the HotSpot JVM.

More info here: [Does a lambda expression create an object on the heap every time it's executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524445/does-a-lambda-expression-create-an-object-on-the-heap-every-time-its-executed)