# why lambda returns identical object

Tags: lambda, java-8

Almost every book introducing lambda beginning with a `Runnable` anonymous class, or even mentioned as an alternative to "anonymous class". However, lambda returns the same object while anonymous class returns a new one.

**1. Why lambda behaves like this?**

**2. Why it is designed to be so?**

[image: example codes and results]

Comment: I think the reason might be to add the possibility to chain-call methods using lambda, like lambda2(lambda()).

Comment: Because you don’t need multiple instances of `Runnable` doing exactly the same thing. The anonymous inner class, however, is connected with the `new` operator, which guarantees to produce a new distinct instance, whether you need it or not. Lambda expressions opened to opportunity to create less objects, which has been explicitly declared in the specification. As explained in [Does a lambda expression create an object on the heap every time it's executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27524445/2711488)…

Comment: Avoiding allocation is a Good Thing™, so there's little reason why it should behave any other way (although it could).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CallSite` is the same in your case, and `linkage` happens per call-site. I think, to better understand this you need to look at what `invokedynamic` is. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524445/does-a-lambda-expression-create-an-object-on-the-heap-every-time-its-executed).

Comment: No, regular developers should not have to understand the low-level mechanics (which are free to change!) in order to use lambdas effectively.  What they have to know is: lambdas come with no guarantee of the uniqueness of their identity, full stop.

Comment: @BrianGoetz then that *regular developer* becomes an *exception bogglehead* because his/her unexpected situation may happen anytime anywhere.

Comment: @Tiina Perhaps I wasn't clear; what I was criticizing was the answer, not the question.  What regular developers should understand is that the _Java Language Specification_ says that lambda expressions do not make any commitment about their identity.  The details of `CallSite` and `invokedynamic` are mere implementation details, which may change, as long as the implementation adheres to the specification.  Users should understand what the _language commits to_, rather than what the _compiler happens to do on any given day._