# Why java 8 introduces iterable.forEach() loop even though it has for each?

Tags: lambda, foreach, java-8

I'm not able to understand why java 8 has forEach loop and taking the Consumer functional interface as parameter. Even though we can do the same task using traditional for each loop without creating any extra overhead to create a class implements that from Consumer and implements a method and then pass this as reference to the forEach(). Although there is lambda expression to make it short.

Q1- why iterable.forEach()?

Q2. Where to use it?

Q3. which one is faster traditional for each of Java 8 forEach()?

Sample:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class ForEachExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //creating sample Collection
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) myList.add(i);

        //traversing using Iterator
        Iterator<Integer> it = myList.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Integer i = it.next();
            System.out.println("Iterator Value::"+i);
        }

        //traversing through forEach method of Iterable with anonymous class
        myList.forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {

            public void accept(Integer t) {
                System.out.println("forEach anonymous class Value::"+t);
            }

        });

        //traversing with Consumer interface implementation
        MyConsumer action = new MyConsumer();
        myList.forEach(action);

    }

}

//Consumer implementation that can be reused
**class MyConsumer implements Consumer<Integer>{
    public void accept(Integer t) {
        System.out.println("Consumer impl Value::"+t);
    }
}**
```

Comment: one reason is clarity of intent and concision: you can write your loop like this: `myList.forEach(System.out::println);` Many things are compatible with the `Consumer` interface, so you can replace many loops with a `forEach` without needing intermediate variable

Comment: iterable.forEach() can only print the data/list. even we can  not access the outer variable inside the lambdaexp. or loop and we can not perform any business operation by accessing the outer data. but still to just print the values it is necessary to use iterable.forEach()?

Comment: I consider not being able to access outer data is a feature, forcing developers to pay attention to side effects

Comment: What do you mean with “outer data”? You *can* access variables from the surrounding context from a lambda expression. In case of local variables they have to be effectively final. By the way, the standard idiom for looping over an iterable for your example is `for(Integer i: myList) System.out.println("Iterator Value::"+i);`

Answer (score 6):

The general idea of the new APIs inspired by Functional Programming is to express *what* to do instead of *how* to do it. Even when using the simplified for-each loop,

```
for(Integer i: myList) System.out.println("Value::"+i);
```

it’s just syntactic sugar for the instructions “acquire an `Iterator` instance and call repeatedly `hasNext()` and `next()` on it”.

In contrast, when using

```
myList.forEach(i -> System.out.println("Value::"+i));
```

you provide an action, to be applied to each element, but don’t specify how to do it. The `default` implementation will just perform the `Iterator` based loop, but actual `Iterable` implementations may override it to perform the operation differently.

Note that a lot of `Iterator` implementations are performing checks twice, once in `hasNext()`, then again in `next()` as there is no guaranty that the caller did `hasNext()` first, to throw a `NoSuchElementException` if there is no next element. Sometimes this even implies holding additional state within the `Iterator` instance to remember whether a particular “fetch-next” operation has been performed already. A dedicated `forEach` implementation can be straight-forward, more efficient while being simpler in code.

For example, `ArrayList` performs an `int`-index based loop without constructing an `Iterator` instance, `Collections.emptyList()` does nothing but checking the `Consumer` against `null`, `TreeSet` resp. its backing `TreeMap` traverses entry links, which is much simpler than its `Iterator` implementation which has to support the `remove` operation, and so on.

Whether a dedicated `forEach` implementation may compensate the `Consumer` construction related overhead, if there is one (mind that [not every lambda expression creates a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488)), is not predictable and assumptions about that should not drive the software design. More than often, the performance differences are negligible.

But there can be semantic differences too. When using one of the collections returned by `Collections.synchronized…`, an `Iterator` based loop can not provide consistency guarantees when the underlying collection is modified by another thread. The application would need to lock on the collection manually and have to care to use the right object instance, e.g. if the iterable is a [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) or [`subSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet-E-E-). In contrast, the specialized `forEach(Consumer)` locks correctly during the entire operation, whereas the operation itself is as simple as delegating to the source’s `forEach` method, to still perform it in the optimal way according to the actual underlying collection.

Answer (score 5):

It just a tasty problem.
If you want something more functional, use `forEach`, but in your case, the traditional for-each loop is good.
In fact, there are two things `for-loop` supports but `forEach` not:

1. flow control keywords like `continue`, `break`, `return`
2. `Checked exception`

Comment: good I forget to mention continue, break, return thanks. anyway vote up

Answer (score 2):

Q1- why iterable.forEach()?

It introduce to reduce the lines of code. Your loop can see in following as old way and new way

old way

```
   for (Integer t : myList) {
        System.out.println("forEach old way Value::"+t);
    }
```

new way

```
   myList.forEach(t ->System.out.println("forEach lambda way::"+t));
```

Q2. Where to use it?

Any where you want to iterate over the collection.

Q3. which one is faster traditional for each of Java 8 forEach()?

Older way and new way both there is no big performance difference. But if you use stream to iterate it has some latency than old for each.

Answer (score 1):

forEach has been created to use lambda syntax :

```
myList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

or

```
myList.forEach(e->System.out.println(e));
```

This is the whole purpose of functional interface