# Does the Internal Iterator use the hasNext() and next() to iterate in Java?

Tags: java, loops, foreach, iterator

I'm learning about internal iterators and I understand that an internal iterator manage the iterations in the background:

```
   public void internalIterator(){
      List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList("Tom", "Dick", "Harry");
      namesList.forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));
   }
```

But I think that enhanced for loop does the same thing:

```
 public void enhancedForLoop(){
  List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList("Tom", "Dick", "Harry");
  for(String name : namesList){
    System.out.println(name);
  }
 }
```

I know that enhanced for loop uses hasNext() and next() methods in the background. And enhanced for loop is an external iterator. Then why forEach() method is an internal iterator? Doesn't forEach() method use hasNext() and next() methods in the background? How the iterations are managed in the backgorund in a different way than enhanced for loop? And is the iteration faster using forEach() than using enhanced for loop? Any feedback will be apreciated?

Comment: The implementation of `forEach` depends on the type of the collection. For example, `ArrayList` uses a standard indexed loop. `LinkedList` inherits the default implementation of `Iterable`, which uses an enhanced for loop. Enhanced for loops use iterators to traverse the collection, so the answer is: it depends on the collection you use.

Comment: @Dioxin Do you have a source for “ArrayList uses a standard indexed loop”?  The final operand of a for-each loop is required to be an Iterable, which implies that a Iterable.iterator() is always used.

Comment: @VGR What do you want to say about "final operand of a for-each loop is required to be an Iterable"? What final operand has the for-each loop? Do you have a link? Thank you!

Comment: @VGR You can check the source code. Here's a link to OpenJDK's `ArrayList#forEach`: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L1505-L1514

Comment: @VGR `iterator()` is not always used. One of the goals behind introducing `forEach` was allowing implementation-specific iteration. `ArrayList` is still `Iterable`. But the devs decided it's more optimal to use indexed looping instead of the list's iterator. `ArrayDeque` also provides it's own `forEach` implementation which doesn't use `iterator()`. As for enhanced-loops, `Iterable` is only one requirement (JLS 14.14.2); when an array is used in an enhanced loop, it translates to an indexed loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also the definition of `forEach` on the interface [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)).
Both constructs use different methods of the same interface.

Conceptually, the difference is that in an "enhanced for loop" the class implementing the `Iterable` only creates the `Iterator`, and the loop construct is responsible for advancing it (see also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)).

When calling `forEach`, the class controls the entire process of iteration, and can pick whatever is most suitable for its underlying data structure. For example, it could avoid creating an `Iterator` object, and instead use some internal array index or similar.

Other than that, they should be equivalent. In most cases I wouldn't expect any difference in performance.

See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021531/2513200) for some additional reasons why you might want to use `forEach`, e.g. additional consistency guarantees when iterating synchronized collections, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018206/2513200) mentioning things that it does not provide, such as flow control (e.g. short-circuiting using `break`) or support for checked exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for response! Does the enhanced for loop always use the Iterator or it could use index counter? I'm looking at the link that you posted and the best answer said: "if the right-hand side of the for (:) idiom is an array rather than an Iterable object, the internal code uses an int index counter and checks against array.length instead"

Comment: Yes, these two cases are explicitly covered in the [JLS 14.14.2. The enhanced for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2). For arrays it uses indices, for `Iterables` it uses `iterator()`, other types are not supported.

Comment: So, "enhanced for loop" use indices for arrays and iterator() for Iterables. And forEach() method isn't for arrays it is only for Iterables, but for Iterables it could use iterator() or indices depending on the collection that it use. Right?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is what the user of the API has to do.

---

## Differences

**External**

When using `iterator()`, it's the user's job (your job) to manage the traversal: when to call `hasNext()` and when to call `next()`. The iteration is handled **externally** from the API, by the user of the API. The user both iterates through the elements & consumes the elements.

**Internal**

When using `forEach`, it's the API's job to manage the traversal. The iteration is handled **internally** instead of by the user; the user only consumes the elements.

---

## Conclusion

It doesn't matter if `hasNext()` and `next()` are being called. What does matter is *who* calls `hasNext()` and `next()` - who handles the iteration, who is in charge of the iterator.

`forEach` is internal because the user doesn't have control over how the elements are iterated through. The API handles it; the iterator is internal.

`iterator()` is external because the user must define how iteration will occur. The API passes you the iterator, and that's all the API does. The iterator is external.

Even though `forEach` uses `iterator()` in some cases, that iterator is still internal to the API you're using (the `List`). Whoever calls `forEach` still only worry about consuming elements. The user doesn't control how the elements are traversed through, so it doesn't matter what `forEach` uses.

---

## Suggestions on when to use a strategy

You'd use an enhanced loop when you need the most basic of sequential iteration.

You'd use an `iterator()` when you need more complex iteration.

You'd use `forEach` when you're only worried about consuming the elements, and don't mind if the API decides on how to traverse through the collection.

Comment: So when you use iterator() is external and when you use forEach is external. What about enhanced for loop?

Comment: @elvis `forEach` is internal. Using an enhanced for loop is no different than using an `iterator()` yourself. The enhanced for loop does is make it so you don't have to write `for (Iterator<String> i = namesList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) { String name = i.next(); ... }` (if using an `Iterable`). But it works the exact same as if you were to write all that code yourself. That's why it's considered "syntactic sugar". So using an enhanced for loop would make use of an external iterator.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say forEach is internal.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know where you got that "enhanced for loop is an external iterator", but `Iterable.forEach` just does the same thing as your second example (could be overridden, though I don't see any reason to).

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: The enhanced for-loop is an external iterator whereas the new forEach method is an internal one: https://www.baeldung.com/foreach-java

Comment: OK, I had not heard that definition either yet, but ok. Btw. I found another related question, but beware the answers there are somewhat opinionated (still some good discussion of the differences, although it mixes in quite a bit of semi-related Stream API discussions): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop?rq=1

Comment: @elvis It looks like the author is trying to get philosophical. I think they are trying to assert some huge difference as one being declarative and the other imperative. I don't know how they can call enhanced for-loop an "external" iterator, when the whole presence of the iterator is hidden. I would ignore that article, seems stupid to me.

Comment: @Michael The terms have been used long before that article was written. Here's an example on Stack Overflow from 2008: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224648/external-iterator-vs-internal-iterator

Comment: @Dioxin That doesn't mean enhanced for-loop is an external iterator. The article says, in reference to an enhance for-loop "*the complexity of these operations is hidden from the programmer but it still exists*". Well, that is exactly the case with `forEach` as well, as you can see from the snippet above.

Comment: @Michael I wasn't saying you were wrong that it can be seen as imperative vs declarative. But any form of an iterator that is managed by the client of the API (calling `hasNext` and `next`) is an external iterator. Enhanced for loops are just syntactic sugar, mentioned in [14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) of the JLS; the API is still exposing an iterator in that case, which the client must control the iteration. The language just hides it for you in cases of the most basic iteration.

Comment: @Dioxin The `forEach` method belongs to `Iterable`. What is that interface doing if not "exposing an iterator"? You will not be able to convince me that's there's a difference, because there isn't one.

Comment: @Michael In the case of `ArrayList.forEach`, the interface does nothing. The implementation used by `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque` don't depend on the `iterator()`, or anything else from `Iterable`. They only override `Iterable.forEach` because they already implemented `Iterable` from the start. They aren't even depending on `Iterable.forEach` (no super call). May as well not be overriding `Iterable.forEach` and simply have each declare it on their own (or introduce a new interface, which I doubt they wanted to do).

Comment: @Dioxin Both the article and the OP are talking about `Iterable.forEach` in the general case. Neither one made any specific reference to ArrayList. You are moving the goalposts, because you never made any claim in your previous 2 comments that it depends on the implementation. What is true for ArrayList is not true for LinkedList, so you cannot say both are internal iterators because of the implementation of one of them. I even said in my answer "could be overridden".

Comment: @Michael He's using `List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList(...)` in his example.. And you're right, it's not the same for all collections. But the idea is, the client of the API doesn't control iteration. You can leave it at "it's just declarative", but you can't get upset that other terms exist man.

Comment: @Dioxin `java.util.ArrayList` != `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220557/discussion-between-dioxin-and-michael).