# Is lambda really an object or not?

Tags: java, lambda

I saw on a tutorial that lambda is not associated with any object that works with **invokedynamic**. But on this site and other sites, I saw that it said that a lambda is an object. Now I do not know if this tutorial is wrong or invokedynamic Is related to object creation? Because I do not know the relation between invokedynamic and object creation.

I visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524445/does-a-lambda-expression-create-an-object-on-the-heap-every-time-its-executed) link but did not get my answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that every lambda was an instance of an object that implements at least one interface, but I have no knowledge of the underlying internals. When you say "object", what exactly do you mean? Since people have multiple definitions of "object"

Comment: I mean the reference variable that is stored in the heap.(like new Integer()).

Comment: In Java or in general in OOP when someone says "object" it means "an instance of a class" period. If people has different definition of an object, they are simply wrong. There's no such thing like *an instance of an object*. Sadly `Object` is also a class but it's not "an object" :-\

Comment: I know what an object is, but he asked what I meant by an object in Lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple bits that need untangling here.

A lambda is an object.  In particular, it's an instance of a functional interface, which has only one abstract method.

Not every occurrence of a lambda makes a *new* object.

`invokedynamic` can, but is not required to, make a new object.

`invokedynamic` is used to get lambda objects, whether or not they are newly created.

Comment: This is technically correct, but highly misleading, I don't think it serves as a good answer as a consequence. In two senses: [A] The JVM explicitly states that it either doesn't have identity, or, if it does, that you can't rely on this identity. If you `synchronized(x)` where x is e.g. `Runnable x = () -> foo;`, or you do `==` equality to check something, or use them as keys in a hashmap, that sort of thing - that's all neccessarily a code bug as the thing doesn't have (defined) identity. [B] In practice, JVMs _do not_ make an object, at all, in certain cases.

Comment: can you explain "Not every occurrence of a lambda makes a new object"?Is it possible that two lambdas with two different bodies have the same reference?

Comment: No, that's not possible.  They would have to have the same bodies.

Comment: @aa5 __There is no reference__ (usably, at least). They do not have a meaningful identity. Because java is java, you can of course write `Runnable r = System.out::println; synchronized (r) {}` (treat it as: It is a reference and that reference can be used for stuff), but that code is gobbledygook. The JVM spec says this is meaningless, Another `Runnable f2 = System.out::println` may or may not be the same reference. If you write this code, i.e. if you write code where 'it is a reference' is relevant in the first place, your code is broken in an untestable way (that's bad). So don't.

Comment: @aa5 Are you asking because you are thinking about the performance impact of lambdas (oh no! It creates objects! That might get pricey! - that kind of thinking), or more thinking about using the notion that a lambda is a reference for something, such as locking on it, using them as a key in a map, or because you want to write some bytecode directly?

Comment: I mean.  There is a reference.  It's the same as any other Java object.  It's just a particularly useless reference.

Comment: @rzwitserloot  No, I just want to know the exact difference between a lambda and an anonymous class

Comment: @aa5 The _exact_ difference cannot be summarized; just read the JLS.

Comment: I recommend you search StackOverflow for the many informative answers about the differences between lambdas and anonymous classes.