# Is an object created when you pass a method reference in a method

Tags: java, lambda

As far as I know, when you define a method in a function, an object is instantiated:

```
myList.stream().map(x->x.getName().replaceAll('a','b')).toList();
```

Or the equivalent

```
 Function<MyObject,String> myFunc = x -> {return x.getName().replaceAll('a','b');}
 myList.stream().map(myFunc).toList();
```

`x->x.getName().replaceAll('a','b')` is created as a functional interface object (and requires memory allocation, a `new` somewhere/somehow, right?).

However, if I pass an already existing method as a parameter, is anything created?

```
class A{
  public list<String> transform(List<String> input){
    return input.stream().filter(this::myFilter).filter(A::staticFilter).toList();
  }
  public boolean myFilter(String s){ // Whatever }
  public static boolean staticFilter(String s) { // whatever }
}
```

What happens here:

- Is `myFilter` "wrapped" in a functional interface? (is it the same for a static method reference?)
- Is there something specific that happens at bytecode level which is not "clear" on language level (like method pointer or something?).

Comment: The answer is "it depends": the spec is intentionally vague as to when/where/by whom an object is created there, how aggressively it might be cached/shared or if a real object is necessary at all to allow the JVM to optimize as it sees fit. It only guarantees that *an object* exists when you pass it, but not where/when it will be created.

Comment: Do you mean `filter(A::staticFilter)` instead of `filter(A.staticFilter)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [JavaDoc Api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)

> Note that instances of functional interfaces can be created with
> lambda expressions, method references, or constructor references.

As to if the lambda expression will create an instance in heap or not, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27524445/7237884) thread where the top comment from @Brian Goetz might be helpful.

**About lambda expressions:**

Also as indicated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4) in Java Specifications for *Run-Time Evaluation of Lambda Expressions*

> These rules are meant to offer flexibility to implementations of the
> Java programming language, in that:
>
> **A new object need not be allocated on every evaluation.**
>
> Objects produced by different lambda expressions need not belong to
> different classes (if the bodies are identical, for example).
>
> Every object produced by evaluation need not belong to the same class
> (captured local variables might be inlined, for example).
>
> If an "existing instance" is available, it need not have been created
> at a previous lambda evaluation (it might have been allocated during
> the enclosing class's initialization, for example).

So to your question:

> x->x.getName().replaceAll('a','b') is created as a functional
> interface object (and requires memory allocation, a new
> somewhere/somehow, right?).

The answer is some times yes, some times no. Not always the same case.

**About [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) expressions:**

> Evaluation of a method reference expression produces an instance of a
> functional interface type (§9.8). Method reference evaluation does not
> cause the execution of the corresponding method; instead, this may
> occur at a later time when an appropriate method of the functional
> interface is invoked.

Based on what is written [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3) for  *Run-Time Evaluation of Method References*

> The timing of method reference expression evaluation is more complex
> than that of lambda expressions (§15.27.4). When a method reference
> expression has an expression (rather than a type) preceding the ::
> separator, that subexpression is evaluated immediately. **The result of
> evaluation is stored until the method of the corresponding functional
> interface type is invoked**; at that point, the result is used as the
> target reference for the invocation. This means the expression
> preceding the :: separator is evaluated only when the program
> encounters the method reference expression, **and is not re-evaluated on
> subsequent invocations on the functional interface type**.

I would assume that a functional interface type is created but not each time with each invocation. It should as well be cached and optimized for the less amount of evaluations.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the compiler has a lot of leeway in how it actually implements the code you write, but generally `.map()` takes a `Function` `Object` so whatever expression you put in the parentheses will produce an object.

That does not mean, however, that a new `Object` is created every time.  In your lambda example, the lambda function doesn't reference anything defined in an enclosing method scope, so a single `Function` object can be created and reused for all calls.

Similarly, the `A::staticFilter` reference only needs to produce one `Function`.

The object created by `this::myFilter`, however, needs to have a reference to `this` (unless the compiler can determine that it doesn't!), and so you will certainly get a new `Function` created inside each call to `transform`.