# Does Java 8's Method Reference use Reflection?

Tags: java, method-reference

I have done a lot of searching around online and have come up with no information on this.  My question is how does Java 8 internally handle Method Referencing e.g. `Car::getWeight`?  Does it use Reflection, or is it an entirely new method of accessing a classes static and non-static methods?

I ask this because I have been learning about it recently and have become somewhat intrigued.  I really enjoy the ability to handle function references just as though they were variables in languages like Python and JS.  To be able to do this (in a somewhat limited capacity) in Java, is really exciting.  Although, if the performance suffers much like with Reflection, it may not be such an exciting prospect.

Consider this example:

```
public class Main {

    private static List<String> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<Supplier<Shape>> constrs = new ArrayList<>();

    static{
        constrs.add(Triangle::new);
        constrs.add(Square::new);
        shapes.add("triangle");
        shapes.add("square");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Shape x = constrs.get(shapes.indexOf("triangle")).get();

        Supplier<String> h = x::dothis;

        System.out.println(h.get());
    }
}
```

There is no way for the compiler to know of what type `x` is at compile time, so how can the compiler replace `x::dothis` with an anonymous method?

Comment: There's no need for reflection. The class and method name are available at compile time, after all.

Comment: What about the case where you may have a `List<Supplier<Parent>>` that holds different `Child::new` and programmatically a constructor is chosen?  Will it still just replace each of those `Supplier<Parent>`s with their respective constructors at compile time even if there is no logical path to them in the code? @user2357112

Comment: It'll basically just write the same reflection-free anonymous classes you would have written if method references (and lambdas) weren't a thing.

Comment: @user2357112 I worked up an example to better illustrate my point, if you would like to take a look.  I also did some mediocre grade (`System.nanoTime()`) testing on this and it seems that there is a significant performance lose when using method reference instead of direct method invocation.

Comment: Hmm. The implementation appears to be [way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) more [complex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983832/is-method-reference-caching-a-good-idea-in-java-8) than the user-level explanation and "equivalent to"s made it seem.