# Java double colon operator reference (::)

Tags: java, java-8

Is

```
test::testMethod == test::testMethod
```

true? I want to find out whether they will refer to the same object. This code does not compile. But there may be several situations in which this needs clarification.

I suspect that this will expand to

```
Runnable r = () -> test.testMethod()
Runnable r1 = () -> test.testMethod()
```

And whether the below is true.

```
r == r1
```

Comment: If the code doesn't compile, then asking whether the result is `true` or not is meaningless. Please provide a complete example that *does* compile.

Comment: I suspect the answer is that it's not specified though - JLS 15.13.3: "Next, either a new instance of a class with the properties below is allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class with the properties below is referenced." (With no details that I can see about the cases in which an instance is reused.)

Comment: See [Does a lambda expression create an object on the heap every time it's executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488). In short, it’s intentionally unspecified. It might be `true`, but doesn’t have to. And in the current JRE, it isn’t. You may also retrace the test of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23991339/2711488) which shows, under which circumstances the objects are the same in the current implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if your code could compile and the `test::testMethod` declared as `Runnable` the answer `test::testMethod == test::testMethod` is always return false, because you comparing with two diff class instances. for each lambda expression the compiler will create a `synthentic` anonymous inner class for it.for example:

```
//a synthentic anonymous lambda class A implemented Runnable
Runnable r = () -> test.testMethod(); 

//a synthentic anonymous lambda class B implemented Runnable
Runnable r1 = () -> test.testMethod();

r.getClass().equals(r1.getClass());// always return false
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the following example:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = String::isEmpty;

Function<String,Boolean> function = String::isEmpty;

System.out.println(predicate.equals(function)); // false
```

A lambda doesn't contain any information about it's type. That information is deduced from the context.  The same lamba `String::inEmpty` can represent different functional interfaces, as we have seen above.