# How Memory assigns to lambda | How does it refered,by non super class reference variable

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, heap-memory

I was creating the implementation of a functional interface, below is my code:

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer = new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
};
```

As per the [Java Documentation (javadoc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2)

> A variable of a class type T can hold a null reference or a reference
> to an instance of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T.

In the code above, the anonymous object is created, which is a subclass of `Consumer`, and can be referred to by reference variable `consumer`, which is fine.

But I saw `Consumer` is a `FunctionalInterface`, so I can also do something like this in Java 8:

**Using Lambda**

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer = t -> System.out.println(t);
```

**OR Using Method Reference**

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer = System.out::println;
```

What I know, no sub classes or anonymous classes are being created in both of the above cases. This is creating couple of confusions to me:

**1 : Since the variable `consumer` is not referring to subclass or Anonymous class of `Consumer`, so isn't this violating the above mentioned concept which is, variable can only refer child/self or `null`?**

**2 : How is memory assigned to lambdas, and how does the JVM handle such at run time?**

Comment: There *are* classes. It's smoke and mirrors.

Comment: this is because JVM will create a subclass of `Consumer` in memory for the  bridge methods of lambda expression / method reference expression.

Comment: @holi-java I havn't find any `.class` file related this in class path.Can you please brief.

Comment: in memory means it is only available in memory and didn't persist into disk. you can see the actual class by `consumer.getClass()`.

Comment: you can see here as further: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-

Comment: No, lambdas are not required to be implemented as anonymous classes. Lambdas are also not required to be objects, just try to use `this` and you will get surprises. The magic is in `invokedynamic` read https://www.infoq.com/articles/Invokedynamic-Javas-secret-weapon for example. If think the quoted part of the doc is not for lambdas (need to be verified).

Comment: Quote was for SE7, there is specific section 15.27 in SE8 to cover lambdas.

Comment: @TheCurious since you have a bounty here... may I ask what is not clear to you from the 3 answers? may be we can detail our answers to be more exact?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all Jean-Baptiste has shown you why the assignment works in the first place.

Now the part that I think that you are missing is the fact that the generated class of `Consumer` in case of `Consumer<Integer> consumer = t -> System.out.println(t);` is only visible at runtime due to `invokedynamic`.

Run your class with a flag :

```
java -Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=/Your/Path
```

And you will notice that there is a generated class (inside a path of folders from your package name of the class) that contains a `.class` file sort of like this `SOQuestion$$Lambda$1.class`.

If you decompile that you will see that it's actually a class that implements `Consumer`:

```
final class org.eugene.so.SOQuestion$$Lambda$1 
            implements java.util.function.Consumer {
     public void accept(java.lang.Object);
}
```

If you look at the generated byte code where your lambda is defined, you will see that the lambda expression is actually de-sugared to a static method (for non-captureting lambdas, it could also be non-static if it is a capturing lambda). The code for it:

```
private static void lambda$main$0(java.lang.Integer);
Code:
   0: getstatic     #3  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3: aload_0
   4: invokevirtual #4  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   7: return
```

As far as how the `VM` manages memory for it, for an non-capturing lambda you will get a singleton, for a capturing-lambda you will get a new instance of each call. The absolute must read is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983832/is-method-reference-caching-a-good-idea-in-java-8/23991339#23991339)

Comment: Hey, what are you doing? you have explained it in more detailed what I said, and the [@Holger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983832/is-method-reference-caching-a-good-idea-in-java-8/23991339#23991339) has described the "*it may include a new class in the linkage phase*" exactly, so you have my +1. good job, :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to refer to SE8 15.27:

> 15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression
>
> A lambda expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation
>   context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional
>   interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the
>   function type of the ground target type derived from T.

Runtime handling use tricky things with `invokedynamic`. Let examine some code:

```
import java.util.function.*;

class R implements Runnable {
  public void run() { System.out.println("there"); }
}

public class L {
  public static void execute(Runnable r) {
    System.out.println(r.getClass());
    r.run();
  }
  public static void main(String []a) {
    execute(new R()); // subclass
    execute(new Runnable() { // anonymous subclass
        public void run() { System.out.println("elsewhere"); }
      });
    execute(() -> System.out.println("here")); // lambda
  }
}
```

Execution gives:

```
> java L
class R
there
class L$1
elsewhere
class L$$Lambda$1/791452441
here
```

For the first two there is no surprise, the class of the object received by method `execute` is (in the given order) `R` (the subtype of `Runnable`), `L$1` (the anonymous subtype of `Runnable`, and `L$$Lambda$1/791452441` (the subtype of `Runnable` constructed at run time from the lambda). Note that in the case of lambda there is no `.class` file, the type is constructed at runtime by special construct. Let's examine the bytecode:

```
> javap -c -v L
Classfile /private/tmp/L.class
  Last modified 1 août 2017; size 1234 bytes
  MD5 checksum 9680a2bc143d25344979bae00fff3db7
  Compiled from "L.java"
public class L
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #15.#28        // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #29.#30        // java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   #3 = Methodref          #15.#31        // java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   #4 = Methodref          #32.#33        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   #5 = InterfaceMethodref #34.#35        // java/lang/Runnable.run:()V
   #6 = Class              #36            // R
   #7 = Methodref          #6.#28         // R."<init>":()V
   #8 = Methodref          #14.#37        // L.execute:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
   #9 = Class              #38            // L$1
  #10 = Methodref          #9.#28         // L$1."<init>":()V
  #11 = InvokeDynamic      #0:#43         // #0:run:()Ljava/lang/Runnable;
  #12 = String             #44            // here
  #13 = Methodref          #32.#45        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #14 = Class              #46            // L
  #15 = Class              #47            // java/lang/Object
  #16 = Utf8               InnerClasses
  #17 = Utf8               <init>
  #18 = Utf8               ()V
  #19 = Utf8               Code
  #20 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #21 = Utf8               execute
  #22 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
  #23 = Utf8               main
  #24 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #25 = Utf8               lambda$main$0
  #26 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #27 = Utf8               L.java
  #28 = NameAndType        #17:#18        // "<init>":()V
  #29 = Class              #48            // java/lang/System
  #30 = NameAndType        #49:#50        // out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #31 = NameAndType        #51:#52        // getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
  #32 = Class              #53            // java/io/PrintStream
  #33 = NameAndType        #54:#55        // println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  #34 = Class              #56            // java/lang/Runnable
  #35 = NameAndType        #57:#18        // run:()V
  #36 = Utf8               R
  #37 = NameAndType        #21:#22        // execute:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
  #38 = Utf8               L$1
  #39 = Utf8               BootstrapMethods
  #40 = MethodHandle       #6:#58         // invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  #41 = MethodType         #18            //  ()V
  #42 = MethodHandle       #6:#59         // invokestatic L.lambda$main$0:()V
  #43 = NameAndType        #57:#60        // run:()Ljava/lang/Runnable;
  #44 = Utf8               here
  #45 = NameAndType        #54:#61        // println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #46 = Utf8               L
  #47 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #48 = Utf8               java/lang/System
  #49 = Utf8               out
  #50 = Utf8               Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #51 = Utf8               getClass
  #52 = Utf8               ()Ljava/lang/Class;
  #53 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
  #54 = Utf8               println
  #55 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  #56 = Utf8               java/lang/Runnable
  #57 = Utf8               run
  #58 = Methodref          #62.#63        // java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  #59 = Methodref          #14.#64        // L.lambda$main$0:()V
  #60 = Utf8               ()Ljava/lang/Runnable;
  #61 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #62 = Class              #65            // java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory
  #63 = NameAndType        #66:#69        // metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  #64 = NameAndType        #25:#18        // lambda$main$0:()V
  #65 = Utf8               java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory
  #66 = Utf8               metafactory
  #67 = Class              #71            // java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup
  #68 = Utf8               Lookup
  #69 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  #70 = Class              #72            // java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles
  #71 = Utf8               java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup
  #72 = Utf8               java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles
{
  public L();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0

  public static void execute(java.lang.Runnable);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: aload_0
         4: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
         7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        10: aload_0
        11: invokeinterface #5,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/lang/Runnable.run:()V
        16: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 11: 0
        line 12: 10
        line 13: 16

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #6                  // class R
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #7                  // Method R."<init>":()V
         7: invokestatic  #8                  // Method execute:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        10: new           #9                  // class L$1
        13: dup
        14: invokespecial #10                 // Method L$1."<init>":()V
        17: invokestatic  #8                  // Method execute:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        20: invokedynamic #11,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:run:()Ljava/lang/Runnable;
        25: invokestatic  #8                  // Method execute:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        28: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 15: 0
        line 16: 10
        line 19: 20
        line 20: 28
}
SourceFile: "L.java"
InnerClasses:
     static #9; //class L$1
     public static final #68= #67 of #70; //Lookup=class java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup of class java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles
BootstrapMethods:
  0: #40 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #41 ()V
      #42 invokestatic L.lambda$main$0:()V
      #41 ()V
```

The first interesting part is the code of `main`:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #6                  // class R
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #7                  // Method R."<init>":()V
         7: invokestatic  #8                  // Method execute:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        10: new           #9                  // class L$1
        13: dup
        14: invokespecial #10                 // Method L$1."<init>":()V
        17: invokestatic  #8                  // Method execute:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        20: invokedynamic #11,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:run:()Ljava/lang/Runnable;
        25: invokestatic  #8                  // Method execute:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        28: return
```

As you can observe there is no difference in between the explicit implementation of the interface or the anonymous one. The last only involves class naming trickery (`L$1`), but both are used the same way, through `invokestatic`.

Interesting case is the third (the lambda one) which involves `invokedynamic` and then `invokestatic`. Note that the `invokestatic` calls the same method as in the two previous calls (the method `run`).

Roughly, the first time the `invokedynamic` is called a bootstrap method is called to construct a `CallSite` (see [CallSite in Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/CallSite.html)) which will then be used further to execute the code of the lambda. See the bootstrap call here:

```
BootstrapMethods:
  0: #40 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #41 ()V
      #42 invokestatic L.lambda$main$0:()V
      #41 ()V
```

and the code referred by the call site:

```
  #41 = MethodType         #18            //  ()V
  #42 = MethodHandle       #6:#59         // invokestatic L.lambda$main$0:()V
  #43 = NameAndType        #57:#60        // run:()Ljava/lang/Runnable;
  #44 = Utf8               here
  #45 = NameAndType        #54:#61        // println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #46 = Utf8               L
  #47 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #48 = Utf8               java/lang/System
  #49 = Utf8               out
  #50 = Utf8               Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #51 = Utf8               getClass
  #52 = Utf8               ()Ljava/lang/Class;
  #53 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
  #54 = Utf8               println
  #55 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  #56 = Utf8               java/lang/Runnable
  #57 = Utf8               run
```

Comment: the bootstrap method will create the `class` file  for the lambda (let's say a class that extends the `java.util.Predicate`). Then internally this `Predicate#test` will call the de-sugared lambda expression (a static inner method inside the class where lambda is used). It will also create a `MethodHandle` to the `test` method (that will be contained within a `CallSite` object); this `CallSite` will be linked to the invocation, exactly once.

Answer (score 6):

**Q**: If here consumer is not referring to subclass or Anonymous class of Consumer ....?

In fact, the subclass is introduced in **Linkage** phase by `invokedynamc` instruction.

> Linkage may involve dynamically **loading** a new class that implements the target interface.  The `CallSite` can be considered a "**factory**" for function objects and so these linkage methods are referred to as "metafactories".

**Q**: How memory assign to lamdas and how does JVM handle such at run time?

It proceeds in order through three phases:

- **Linkage** - may involve dynamically loading a new class that implements the target interface.
- **Capture** - producing a function object.
- **Invocation**  - an implemented interface method is invoked on a function object.

For the more details, you can see [LambdaMetafactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) as further.