# ArrayStoreException in array of Consumers<X>

Tags: java, arrays, reference, observer-pattern, consumer

I’m storing references to `BiConsumers<Integer, X>` adapted to `Consumer<Integer>`:

```
public void setConsumer(BiConsumer<Integer, X> consumer) {
    fieldConsumer = integer -> consumer.accept(integer, fieldSubject);
}
```

But I need 2 of them, so I changed the code to use an array:

```
private Consumer<Integer>[] fieldConsumers;

public MyClass(int numberOfConsumers) {
    Consumer<Integer> consumer = integer -> {};
    fieldConsumers= (Consumer<Integer>[]) Array.newInstance(consumer.getClass(), numberOfObservers);
}

public void addConsumer(int consumerIndex, BiConsumer<Integer, X> consumer) {
    // Offending line
    fieldConsumers[consumerIndex] = responseType-> consumer.accept(responseType, fieldSubject);

}
```

So that the callback can be triggered with a:

```
for (Consumer<Integer> consumer: fieldConsumers) {
    consumer.accept(responseType);
}
```

I got the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
```

on this line:

```
fieldConsumers[consumerIndex] = responseType-> consumer.accept(responseType, fieldSubject);
```

Now, If you are still reading this, I have one more question:

Am I still holding reference to outside Consumers if I do it this way, as opposed to using the old `fieldConsumers.add(consumer)` where fieldConsumers is a `List<BiConsumer<Integer, X>>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `Array.newInstance(consumer.getClass(), numberOfObservers)` to create the `Consumer<Integer>[]` array. But `consumer.getClass()` returns the actual class of the object you’re invoking the method on, which is always an *implementation class* of the interface. An array of this element type can only hold objects of the same concrete class, not arbitrary implementations of the interface.

This is not different to, e.g.

```java
CharSequence cs = "hello";
CharSequence[] array = (CharSequence[]) Array.newInstance(cs.getClass(), 1);
array[0] = new StringBuilder();
```

Here, `cs` has the type `CharSequence` and the reflective array creation appears to create an array of type `CharSequence[]`, so storing a `StringBuilder` should be possible. But since `cs.getClass()` returns the actual implementation class `String`, the array is actually of type `String[]`, hence, the attempt to store a `StringBuilder` produces an `ArrayStoreException`.

In case of lambda expressions, things get slightly more complicated, as the actual implementation classes of the functional interface are provided at runtime and intentionally unspecified. You used the lambda expression `integer -> {}` for the array creation in the constructor, which evaluated to a different implementation class than the `responseType-> consumer.accept(responseType, fieldSubject)` within the `addConsumer` method, *in this particular runtime*.

This behavior is in line with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23991339/2711488) describing the behavior of the most commonly used environment. Still, other implementations could exhibit different behavior, e.g. evaluate to the same implementation class for a particular functional interface for all lambda expressions. But it’s also possible that multiple evaluations of the same lambda expression produce different classes.

So the fix is to use the intended interface element type, e.g.

```java
fieldConsumers=(Consumer<Integer>[])Array.newInstance(Consumer.class, numberOfObservers);
```

But there is no need for a reflective array creation at all. You can use:

```java
fieldConsumers = new Consumer[numberOfObservers];
```

You can not write `new Consumer<Integer>[numberOfObservers]`, as generic array creation is not allowed. That’s why the code above uses a raw type. Using Reflection instead wouldn’t improve the situation, as it is an unchecked operation in either case. You might have to add `@SuppressWarnings` for it. The cleaner alternative is to use a `List<Consumer<Integer>>`, as it shields you from the oddities of arrays and generics.

It’s not clear what you mean with “reference to outside Consumers” here. In either case, you have references to `Consumer` implementations capturing references to `BiConsumer` implementations you received as arguments to `addConsumer`.

Comment: Amazing response, thank you very much @Holger!!

Comment: By "holding reference" I meant if I was capturing a reference to the object captured by the lambda, as I was wrongly believing (at the time I did this question) that simply by not escaping the method stack of the class, I was somehow preventing a reference holding (by the class), what I found out later, is that lambdas behave/are static classes themselves, and the references they capture are stored as field constants inside them.
So the answer is a little complex: Yes I would be holding reference, but it is only a problem depending on which place specifically the root is being detached,

Comment: if the producer is detached then all consumers are detached, as long as they are not waiting to accept/consume from some other attached thread.