# Java lambdas/method references used as callbacks in addCallback/removeCallback style methods

Tags: java, android, lambda, method-reference

I've read about this but I haven't found a clear answer.

Assume an API like the following:

```
Callback callback = new Callback();
myApi.addCallback(callback);
[...]
myApi.removeCallback(callback);
```

Now, if I were to replace with lambdas:

```
myApi.addCallback(() -> whatever());
[...]
myApi.removeCallback(() -> otherWhatever());
```

This obviously would not work, since we are referring different callbacks.

However, what about this?

```
myApi.addCallback(() -> whatever());
[...]
myApi.removeCallback(() -> whatever());
```

Or this?

```
myApi.addCallback(this::whatever);
[...]
myApi.removeCallback(this::whatever);
```

Or this one?

```
myApi.addCallback(StaticClassAccess::whatever);
[...]
myApi.removeCallback(StaticClassAccess::whatever);
```

Comment: The equality of the objects produced for lambda expressions and method references is intentionally unspecified. In practice, this code [will not work in common Java implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23991339/2711488) (HotSpot/OpenJDK) I don’t know whether Android differs but regardless of whether it happens to work in a specific environment, you should not rely on a behavior that is intentionally unspecified.

Comment: For completeness: you can simply stick to your original code pattern of using a variable, `Callback callback = () -> whatever(); myApi.addCallback(callback); [...] myApi.removeCallback(callback);` Then, it doesn’t matter whether semantically equivalent lambda expressions are equal or not, as the variable will contain the same reference in `addCallback` and `removeCallback`, which is all you need.